# JavaFX mp3 playback became unsupported in Ubuntu 14.10

Tags: ubuntu, mp3, javafx-8

When I try to play .mp3 file by using AudioClip with `JavaFX 8u40` it says:

```
com.sun.media.jfxmedia.MediaException: Could not create player!
```

which means Java installation do not see my mp3 codec - but all other OS programs see it, even programs on Qt can play mp3.

This error happened after upgrading to Ubuntu 14.10 (On 14.04 all was fine, the same programs play all the media formats) libav...  all packages are all installed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaFx MediaPlayer "Could not create player!" error in Ubuntu 14.04](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24090356/javafx-mediaplayer-could-not-create-player-error-in-ubuntu-14-04)

Comment: upd: java 8 is currently supporting libav(codec|format)54 while ubuntu 14.10 goes with 56 version installed.