# JavaFX media player on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: java, ubuntu, javafx

I tried to play simple mp3 file using javafx media player, and on windows everything works smoothly, how ever same code on Ubuntu 16.04 results in this error :

> Exception in Application start method
>   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
>       at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
>       at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$155(LauncherImpl.java:182)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>   Caused by: MediaException: UNKNOWN : com.sun.media.jfxmedia.MediaException: Could not create player! : com.sun.media.jfxmedia.MediaException: Could not create player!
>       at javafx.scene.media.MediaException.exceptionToMediaException(MediaException.java:146)
>       at javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer.init(MediaPlayer.java:511)
>       at javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer.(MediaPlayer.java:414)
>       at Test.start(Test.java:24)
>       at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$162(LauncherImpl.java:863)
>       at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175(PlatformImpl.java:326)
>       at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.java:295)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.java:294)
>       at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
>       at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
>       at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.lambda$null$49(GtkApplication.java:139)
>       ... 1 more
>   Caused by: com.sun.media.jfxmedia.MediaException: Could not create player!
>       at com.sun.media.jfxmediaimpl.NativeMediaManager.getPlayer(NativeMediaManager.java:274)
>       at com.sun.media.jfxmedia.MediaManager.getPlayer(MediaManager.java:118)
>       at javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer.init(MediaPlayer.java:467)
>       ... 11 more

And i dont think i am making any mistake, did anyone have similar problems under ubuntu because i have no idea what is causing this.

```
public class Test extends Application {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);

}


@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    String musicFile = "/home/wrongway/Downloads/aaa.mp3";     // For example

    Media sound = new Media(new File(musicFile).toURI().toString());
    //  Media sound = new Media(musicFile.toString());
    System.out.println(musicFile.toString());
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(sound);
    mediaPlayer.play();
}
```

}

Comment: Have u looked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24090356/javafx-mediaplayer-could-not-create-player-error-in-ubuntu-14-04?

Comment: i have tried installing all of that but with no success, i have java 1.8.0_92 version though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My bad guys, i was not aware until now that ubuntu 16.04 was not among supported operating systems for javafx 1.8.

My apologies!

Comment: LOL, [a bug report](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8150503) here. It's fixed in Java 9.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem. Turns out that `MP3` files are not supported for `JavaFX` under `Ubuntu 16.04`, but works fine for `WAV files`.