# JavaFX MediaPlayer throws java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Tags: java, javafx, uri, media-player

I've been trying to experiment with the JavaFX MediaPlayer class, and found the following example code in a different thread:

```
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.media.Media;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class test extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage)
    {
        //Add a scene
        Group root = new Group();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 500, 200);
        URI file = null;
        try {
            file = new URI("/home/thomas/voodoo.mp3");
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("POOR URI SYNTAX");
        }
        Media pick = new Media(file.toString());
        MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer(pick);
        player.play();

        //Add a mediaView, to display the media. Its necessary !
        //This mediaView is added to a Pane
        MediaView mediaView = new MediaView(player);
        ((Group)scene.getRoot()).getChildren().add(mediaView);

        //show the stage
        primaryStage.setTitle("Media Player");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
         launch(args);
    }
}
```

I adjusted the file path to point to a real audio file (/home/thomas/voodoo.mp3) and tried running it, but the console output is the following:

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$1(LauncherImpl.java:182)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: uri.getScheme() == null! uri == '/home/thomas/voodoo.mp3'
    at com.sun.media.jfxmedia.locator.Locator.<init>(Locator.java:211)
    at javafx.scene.media.Media.<init>(Media.java:393)
    at test.start(test.java:28)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$8(LauncherImpl.java:863)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$7(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$5(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$6(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.lambda$null$5(GtkApplication.java:139)
    ... 1 more
Exception running application test
```

Is there something wrong with my setup, or with my code?

Thanks for the help!

EDIT:

Changed to `Media pick = new Media(new File("/home/thomas/voodoo.mp3").toURI().toString());` as per Nash's suggestion, but it still doesn't work. The console output is a little different now, though.

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$1(LauncherImpl.java:182)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: MediaException: UNKNOWN : com.sun.media.jfxmedia.MediaException: Could not create player! : com.sun.media.jfxmedia.MediaException: Could not create player!
    at javafx.scene.media.MediaException.exceptionToMediaException(MediaException.java:146)
    at javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer.init(MediaPlayer.java:511)
    at javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer.<init>(MediaPlayer.java:414)
    at test.start(test.java:20)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$8(LauncherImpl.java:863)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$7(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$5(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$6(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.lambda$null$5(GtkApplication.java:139)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: com.sun.media.jfxmedia.MediaException: Could not create player!
    at com.sun.media.jfxmediaimpl.NativeMediaManager.getPlayer(NativeMediaManager.java:274)
    at com.sun.media.jfxmedia.MediaManager.getPlayer(MediaManager.java:118)
    at javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer.init(MediaPlayer.java:467)
    ... 11 more
Exception running application test
```

Comment: Now that you are passing a full and correct URI to the Media constructor, it appears the file either cannot be read or is not a valid MP3 file.  See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/media/package-summary.html .

Answer (score 2):

The problem is your url `/home/thomas/voodoo.mp3` that is not valid, indeed the scheme is missing as described into your error message (`uri.getScheme() == null! uri == '/home/thomas/voodoo.mp3'`), it should start with `file://` as it is a file in your local file system such that it should be `file:///home/thomas/voodoo.mp3`.

But since it is too error prone to build the `URI` as you currently do because you must ensure that it is properly `URL` encoded (spaces should be for example replaced with `%20`) and you need to provide a valid scheme, you had better to use `new File(path).toURI().toString()` as proposed by [**Nash**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5905194/nash).

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
Media pick = new Media(new File("/home/thomas/voodoo.mp3").toURI().toString());
```

Comment: Still having problems. See above.

Comment: Ok, so what OS and jdk are you running? Could [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24090356/javafx-mediaplayer-could-not-create-player-error-in-ubuntu-14-04) apply to your problem?
I am running this without problems on win10, jdk 1.80_101

Comment: I use Manjaro linux. I have ffmpeg installed. Are there other packages that I would need instead/as well?

Comment: I don't really know. Could your issue be related to [this](https://github.com/NetLogo/vid/issues/9). [Apparently](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8154378) it was fixed in 8u102. So I suggest to upgrade your jdk if you haven't already.