# How to install missing libs on Ubuntu 18.10 to playback video using OpenJFX 11

Tags: ubuntu, openjfx

I am recently installed OpenJDK 11 and OpenJFX 11 on my Ubuntu 18.10.

It gives me an error

> com.sun.media.jfxmedia.MediaException: could not create player

when I am trying to play mp4. Looks like I missed some libraries. What is a correct way to install missing dependencies on Ubuntu 18.10? I found some recommendations for Ubuntu 16...That solution is outdated.

Answer (score 0):

This is likely an issue with codecs. While this is for different version, your question sounds like a duplicate to this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28905158/3514658

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I need to install `ffmpeg-compat-57`package to make `MediaPlayer` work with Java8. I'm using Manjaro Linux (Arch based), the package is located in AUR